# TypeORM - Many-to-Many-to-One Save and/or Update (No entity column was found)

Tags: typescript, many-to-many, nestjs, typeorm

When I save companies, I want to save the addresses and address type associated with the company.

I've been googling around for hours and see a lot of questions on this subject, but nothing I've tried seems to work.

I get the following error when trying to write the object from both Postman and my angular app:

```
[Nest] 27252   - 02/22/2021, 9:41:25 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] No entity column "company_id" was found. +11587ms
EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column "company_id" was found.
    at new EntityColumnNotFound (F:\Development\Sapience\programming\sapience-api\node_modules\typeorm\error\EntityColumnNotFound.js:10:28)
    at F:\Development\Sapience\programming\sapience-api\node_modules\typeorm\query-builder\UpdateQueryBuilder.js:346:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at UpdateQueryBuilder.createUpdateExpression (F:\Development\Sapience\programming\sapience-api\node_modules\typeorm\query-builder\UpdateQueryBuilder.js:342:85)
    at UpdateQueryBuilder.getQuery (F:\Development\Sapience\programming\sapience-api\node_modules\typeorm\query-builder\UpdateQueryBuilder.js:44:21)
    at UpdateQueryBuilder.QueryBuilder.getQueryAndParameters (F:\Development\Sapience\programming\sapience-api\node_modules\typeorm\query-builder\QueryBuilder.js:243:26)
    at UpdateQueryBuilder.<anonymous> (F:\Development\Sapience\programming\sapience-api\node_modules\typeorm\query-builder\UpdateQueryBuilder.js:91:50)
    at step (F:\Development\Sapience\programming\sapience-api\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:141:27)
    at Object.next (F:\Development\Sapience\programming\sapience-api\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:122:57)
    at F:\Development\Sapience\programming\sapience-api\node_modules\typeorm\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:115:75
```

My tables (slightly sanitized for illustration):

```
 +------------------+--------------+----------------------------+
  |                              company                         |
  +------------------+--------------+----------------------------+
  | id               | int          | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
  | name             | varchar(255) |                            |
  +------------------+--------------+----------------------------+

  +------------------+--------------+----------------------------+
  |                          company_address                     |
  +------------------+--------------+----------------------------+
  | company_id       | int          |                            |
  | address_id       | int          |                            |
  +------------------+--------------+----------------------------+

  +------------------+--------------+----------------------------+
  |                              address                         |
  +------------------+--------------+----------------------------+
  | id               | int          | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
  | name             | varchar(255) |                            |
  | address_type_id  | int          |                            |
  +------------------+--------------+----------------------------+

  +------------------+--------------+----------------------------+
  |                           address_type                       |
  +------------------+--------------+----------------------------+
  | id               | int          | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
  | name             | varchar(255) |                            |
  +------------------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

The json:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Sweet Company",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Corporate Office",
            "addressType": {
                "id": 1,
                "description": "Office"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Warehouse",
            "addressType": {
                "id": 2,
                "description": "Storage Facility"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The Company entity.

```
...
    @ManyToMany(() => Address, { cascade: true })
    @JoinTable({
        name:"company_address",
        joinColumn: {
            name: "company_id",
            referencedColumnName: "id"
        },
        inverseJoinColumn: {
            name: "address_id",
            referencedColumnName: "id"
        }
    })
    addresses: Address[];
...
```

The Address entity:

```
...
    @OneToOne(() => AddressType)
    @JoinColumn({ name: "address_type_id" })
    addressType: AddressType;
...
```

The CreateCompanyDto:

```
import { Address } from "src/addresses/entities/address.entity";

export class CreateCompanyDto {
    name: string;
    addresses: Address[];
}
```

The CompainesService

```
...
  create(createCompanyDto: CreateCompanyDto): Promise<Company> {
    const company = new Company();
    company.name = createCompanyDto.name;
    company.addresses = createCompanyDto.addresses;
    return this.repository.save(company);
  }
...
```

Comment: I don't use decorators in TypeOrm myself, but I don't see any param passed in to your anon functions ```@ManyToMany((type) => Address, { cascade: true })``` not sure if that is needed?

Comment: I'll have to dig into that. Not exactly sure what you mean.